# Multiple openlayers 3/4 map instances at the same time in an angular 2/4/5 app?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have openlayers included not as a module, but I create a custom component that takes in the name of a div that gets turned into a map. Is there some way in angular 2/4/5 to make it so that I can have 2 openlayers 3/4 map on the same page?

Comment: I expect Users with 8k+ to write good questions ;-) What did you try, what failed? Did you use some kind of angular-openlayers module or the regular `ol` module? OpenLayers does not stop you from using it multiple times on a page.